# how to calculate velocity of leg using kinect

Tags: c#, kinect-sdk

I have group of skeleton joints, for example 4 joints of leg. Each joint have (x, y, z) coordinates. So I want to find the combine speed or velocity of these group of joints because i believe I need to calculate velocity of each four joints of leg in order to find out the velocity of leg, please correct me If I'm wrong.
So what would be best possible way to calculate?

I'm using this formula

velocity= Sqrt((x[n]−x[n − 1] )2 + (y[n]−y[n − 1] )2 + (z[n]−z[n − 1] )2)

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler equation: Average Velocity = (Delta Distance)/(Delta Time)

If you want to know the average velocity at some point in the leg, calculate the location before it moved & the location on impact. Divide the magnitude of the vector of the difference between the 2 points by the amount of time it took to move between those points.

Comment: Note - to measure force, multiply the velocity by the Mass of the leg and the Sin(angle of attack)